# Android system folders

Tags: android

where can i get documentation about system folders such as /dev /sys /system 
I want to know what normally exists in such folders 
(I want Operating system internals information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android operating system is based on linux so you would be best starting with the [standard linux structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

You should be aware that all versions will be modified slightly so a precise definition of what folders are there may change depending on the device and manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Merlin answer seems good, but I really explore internal memory of my phone using [DroidExplorer](http://de.codeplex.com/)

so you can discover system folders. good luck